# I wrote code that checks if csgo is a running process, but its not updating

Tags: c#

```
public void HookGame()
{
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process process in processList)
    {
        label2.Dispose();
        label3.Show();

        if (process.ProcessName.Contains("csgo"))
        {
            timer2.Start();
            label4.Text = "Csgo is running";
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(label4.Left = (this.Width - label4.Width), 200);
            label4.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            label4.Text = "Csgo is not running";
            this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(label4.Left = (this.Width - label4.Width), 200);
            Refresh();
            label4.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

I called the function on timer3 which is a 5000 interval timer.

```
private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HookGame();
}
```

Called the timer3 on the formload.

Ok the issue is when I open csgo, the timer2 starting which it should be, but the label text doesn't change, its weird tbh can someone help me about that?

I tried making label4 dispose and show again but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an unhandled exception is thrown in a timer event handler in a Windows Forms app, it will stop the timer that raised the exception, and any subsequent timer events will not be raised until the timer is restarted.

It looks like the problem might be that you are disposing the `label2` control many times which can cause an exception to be thrown.

Instead of disposing the control, you could try hiding it by setting its `Visible` property to false or just using [`Hide()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.hide) method. You can also simplify the code by only updating the label text and location when the process is found and by finding process by name instead of iterating through all processes:

```
public void HookGame()
{
    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcessesByName("csgo");
    bool csgoFound = processList.Length > 0;

    label2.Hide();
    label3.Show();

    label4.Text = csgoFound ? "Csgo is running" : "Csgo is not running";
    label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(label4.Left = (this.Width - label4.Width), 200);
    label4.Show();
}
```

Note that you do not need to restart the timer if it has already been started because [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer) implements a timer that raises an event **at user-defined intervals**.

Comment: Thanks! its working right now, i wonder if i want to start timer if csgo is running? im little bit confused about your correction.

Comment: @Mert As far as I understand from your question you have already started the timer inside the method initializecomponent. But now i understand that it was another timer timer3 not timer2. So it’s ok to start another timer but it will start each time your method that checks state of csgo running. To prevent duplicate start you can check Enabled property first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer.enabled

Comment: `          if (processList.Length > 0)
            {
                timer2.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                timer2.Stop();
            }`

It will solve my problem i guess.

Comment: @Mert great! Yes it will work good